# How can I get first in and last out with night shift

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query to get First In and Last Out with Total Hours during daytime and I just want to get the First In, Last Out and Total Hours with Night Shift difference.

```
SELECT 
  bio_id,
  bioname,
  DATE(attendance_datetime) as attendance_date,
  min(TIME(attendance_datetime)) as time_in,
  max(TIME(attendance_datetime)) as time_out,
  TIMEDIFF(max(TIME(attendance_datetime)),min(TIME(attendance_datetime))) as total_hours
FROM `bio_info` 
GROUP BY bio_id,DATE(attendance_datetime)
```

This is my Data

```
id     bioname     attendance_datetime   
1      test        2021-01-18 15:22:13 PM 
2      test        2021-01-19 00:05:49 AM
3      test        2021-01-19 15:00:32 PM
4      test        2021-01-20 00:06:22 AM
5      test        2021-01-20 14:57:20 PM
6      test        2021-01-20 23:58:23 PM
```

And here is the result

```
id     bioname     attendance_date     time_in     time_out       total_hours
1      test        2021-01-18          15:22:13 PM 00:00:00 AM    00:00:00
2      test        2021-01-19          00:05:49 AM 15:00:32 PM    14:54:43
3      test        2021-01-20          00:06:22 AM 23:58:23 PM    23:52:01
```

This is the result that I wanted.

```
id     bioname     attendance_date     time_in     time_out       total_hours
1      test        2021-01-18          15:22:13 PM 00:05:49 AM    08:43:36
2      test        2021-01-19          15:00:32 PM 00:06:22 AM    09:05:50
3      test        2021-01-20          14:57:20 PM 23:58:23 PM    09:01:03
```

Comment: Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT bioname, 
                attendance_datetime,
                1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bioname ORDER BY attendance_datetime) rn
         FROM bio_info )
SELECT rn DIV 2 id,
       bioname, 
       MIN(attendance_datetime) attendance_in, 
       MAX(attendance_datetime) attendance_out,
       TIMEDIFF(MAX(attendance_datetime), MIN(attendance_datetime)) total_hours
FROM cte
GROUP BY id, bioname
ORDER BY bioname, id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd97b843d950d0e6f1000952f3fe4d50)

The query assimes that the data is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on mysql 8.0 or higher than you can use analytical function as follows:

```
select bio_id,
bioname,
DATE(attendance_datetime) as attendance_date,
min(case when rn_i = 1 then TIME(attendance_datetime) end) as time_in,
max(case when rn_o = 1 then TIME(attendance_datetime) end) as time_out,
TIMEDIFF(max(case when rn_o = 1 then TIME(attendance_datetime) end)
         ,min(case when rn_i = 1 then TIME(attendance_datetime) end)) as total_hours
(SELECT t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by DATE(attendance_datetime) 
                           order by TIME(attendance_datetime)) as rn_i,
        row_number() over (partition by DATE(attendance_datetime) 
                           order by TIME(attendance_datetime) desc) as rn_o
FROM `bio_info` t) t
WHERE 1 in (rn_i, rn_o)
GROUP BY bio_id,DATE(attendance_datetime)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but base on your query there's 2 error
"An alias was previously found. (near "t" at position 692)
Unexpected token. (near "t" at position 692)" and I want to figure it out but by the way thanks for your help